# Form submisssion get blocked in IFrame in power bi service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I develope web application using python & Fask having form submission in it which connects to sql server database. Then used that application URL in iframe as source in column of power bi table shared image below and publish that report on service.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bogfd.png)

I used HTML Viewer visual to open that web application and it opens that web application but when I try to submit form, I get error  - "Blocked form submission to '/add_destplat' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set. "
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wWB1.png)

But as you can see in first image I already provided sandboxed attributes "allow-scripts allow-forms". How I can submit the form in IFrame?Any help will be great.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Sometimes when you click a link from an application, the tab opened will have JavaScript disabled/sandboxed.

Close the tab and reopen the same URL in a fresh tab, it might work.